# Can you limit a directory size?

Tags: windows-server-2003, ntfs, disk-space-utilization, network-share

On a single NTFS drive, is it possible to limit the size of a directory to an arbitrary amount (e.g., 20GB)?

I've got a share on a server I want some users to be dumping files into, but I don't want them to be able to fill the drive. I figure I could repartition the drive and mount on of the partitions, but I'd rather not have to take this box off line for that long.

n.b., I'm using Windows 2003 SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a quota for the group on that volume.

Comment: OK, I think I've found out how to do that for a single User (Drive->Properties->Quota->Quota Entries->Quota->New Quota Entry...) what about for a whole group. When ever I try to include one, if can't find the group (even the local one).

Comment: Never mind, I'll it deservers to be its own question.

Comment: Aha. Quotas only exist for users. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Directory Quotas were introduced to Windows in Server 2003 R2. Below that, there aren't any. We make great use of them in our network. They work pretty solid on 2008.

Comment: I presume that would not include Win2003 SP2 then.

Comment: That is correct, 2003sp2 does not have them, alas.

Comment: Quotas will work on the volume, just not per directory.